# PairArr::operator=(PairArr(ValArrInt(ytemp, NY),ValArrInt(btemp,NY)));

Tags: c++

```
template <typename T1,typename T2>
class Pair
{
private:
    T1 a;
    T2 b;
public:
T1 & first() { return a; }
T2 & second() { return b; }
T1 first() const { return a; }
T2 second() const { return b; }
Pair(const T1 & aval, const T2 & bval) : a(aval), b(aval) {};
Pair() {}
};

using ValArrInt = std::valarray<int>;
using PairArr = Pair<ValArrInt, ValArrInt>;

class Wine : private string, private PairArr
{
private:
    int NY;
public:
    Wine(const char * l, int y, const int yr[], const int bot[]);
    void Show() const;
};

Wine::Wine(const char * l, int y, const int yr[], const int bot[])
    :string(l), NY(y)
{
    PairArr::operator=(PairArr(ValArrInt(yr, NY), ValArrInt(bot, NY)));
}

void Wine::Show() const
{
    cout << "Wine: " << (const string &)*this << endl;
    cout << "\tYear\tBottles\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < NY; i++)
    {
        cout << "\t" << PairArr::first()[i] << "\t"
            << PairArr::second()[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

In this line:

```
PairArr::operator=(PairArr(ValArrInt(yr, NY), ValArrInt(bot, NY)));
```

Why does the `PairArr` component end up with `ValArrInt(yr, NY)` (the first argument) being both its a, and b members.

Tested with this:

```
    const int YRS = 3;
    int y[YRS] = { 1993,1995,1998 };
    int b[YRS] = { 48,60,72 };
    Wine more("Gushing Grap Red", YRS, y, b);
    more.Show();
```

off-topic:
Keeps asking me to add more details for the amount of code... But no.
Is there some sort of ratio of code to non-code I'm supposed to meet?

Comment: can you provide code of implementation of Pair cons and assignment operator?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are asked to show a code implementation, because you are here to learn, not to get your work done by us. Please provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so it's much easier for us to help you.

Comment: @Yola Added more code

Comment: @MarioCianciolo Sorry for any inconvenience

Comment: @EmNuggets I'm sorry I was rude. There is no code to non-code ratio. When a question contains compilable and executable code, is way much easier for everyone to compile it and try to tell what's wrong, also this shows that you put some effort trying something, and you're not just submitting homework. This tipically leads to more answers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, apparently you have a misprint, you typed `aval` in both places:

```
Pair(const T1 & aval, const T2 & bval) : a(aval), b(aval) {};
```